# Cómo podria eliminar un elemento de una lista que no sea el primero ni el ultimo?

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
void  EliminarGrupo(grupo *root, char nombre[]){

    int r = 1;
    while(root != NULL){
        if(strcmp(root->gpo,nombre)==0){
            if(r == 1){
                p = head;
                q= p->nextgrupo;
                head = q;
                p->nextgrupo= NULL;
                free(p);    
            }
            if(r>1 && root->nextgrupo==NULL){
                q= head;
                p= head;
                while(q->nextgrupo!=NULL){
                    p=q;
                    q=q->nextgrupo;
                }
                p->nextgrupo=NULL;
                free(q);
            }
            if(r>1 && root->nextgrupo!=NULL){

            }
        }
        root= root->nextgrupo;
        r++;
    }
}
```

Con este código he logrado eliminar elementos que se encuentran al inicio y al final de la lista, pero lo que no he podido entender es como podría eliminar elementos que no sean el primero ni el ultimo.

Comment: ¿Es una lista doblemente enlazada o simple? edita tu post principal para ver como es la estructura de datos root y explicarte bien. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola Jose Roman, sería ideal si pudieras editar la pregunta para especificar mejor tu estructura de datos. Tal y como está redactada la pregunta ahora mismo, faltaría esa parte para poder ayudarte mejor. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo de una tarea de la universidad, te podría servir de referencia.

```
void BorrarEntre(int posicion){
    if(!ListaVacia()){
            int cont = 1;
            Temporal = Cabeza;
            while(cont < posicion - 1 && Temporal->Siguiente){
                Temporal = Temporal->Siguiente;
                cont++;
            }
            Nodo* Refuerzo;
            Refuerzo = Temporal->Siguiente;
            Temporal->Siguiente = Temporal->Siguiente->Siguiente;
            Borrar(Refuerzo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y pueden no ser de ayuda al usuario que pregunta o a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema. Edita la respuesta para añadir una pequeña descripción de lo que hace este código y cómo soluciona el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información.